# What time before the expiry of a visa could I enter France?

Tags: schengen, france, afghan-citizens

Can I enter to France to visit Paris when just two days remains from my tourist visa?

I want to know the immigration officer or the border police will stop me at the airport.

Is there any risk of deportation?

If I have a luggage with 30kg weight will it be a problem?

Won't they ask why I bring this much weight for these few days?

If I have return tickets and hotel reservation can I persuading them that I will just visit Paris for two nights during Christmas and not over stay?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I enter to France to visit Paris when just two days remains from my tourist visa?

Yes you can, **BUT** read further.

> If I have a luggage with30kg Wight will it be a problem? Wont they ask why I bring this much Wight for these few days?

You collect the luggage *after* clearing immigration, so this shouldn't be a problem. However, if taken aside for secondary inspection, they may look at your luggage, and *then* they are very likely to ask about the amount of luggage. I suppose you have an explanation for it.

> If I have return tickets and hotel reservation can I persuading them that I will just visit Paris for two nights during the Christmas and do not over stay?

Well, the return ticket and hotel reservation are a good start, but it will be up to the officer whether you get in.

Be ready to explain why you haven't used your visa up until now.

Comment: If the officers are suspicious of you and refer you for further questioning, they might retrieve your luggage. If you've reached that point, someone may well ask why you have so much stuff for such a short visit. There are explanations that, if truthful, may be satisfactory (e.g. you're on your way to/from somewhere else), but it could be another red flag if you've already given them cause to check into your story.